# Javascript Count the amout of a cetain element

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists, element

I have some javascript that returns a chunk of code, this code contains a mostly random amount of `<li>` elements, a sample output would be:

```
<li class="shiny-box choice clearfix" data-choice-id="0">
    <span class="index">1.</span>
    <span class="val ">vīta vītae f.</span>
    <span class="marking-icon"></span>
</li>
<li class="shiny-box choice clearfix" data-choice-id="1">
    <span class="index">2.</span>
    <span class="val ">patria patriae f.</span>
    <span class="marking-icon"></span>
</li>
<li class="shiny-box choice clearfix" data-choice-id="2">
    <span class="index">3.</span>
    <span class="val ">poena poenae f.</span>
    <span class="marking-icon"></span>
</li>
<li class="shiny-box choice clearfix" data-choice-id="3">
    <span class="index">4.</span>
    <span class="val ">fortūna fortūnae f.</span>
    <span class="marking-icon"></span>
</li>
```

I need a way, in ***vanilla*** javascript to return in array format, the contents of the `class=val` spans.

An example of the output of this code would be:

```
var array = ["vīta vītae f.","patria patriae f.","poena poenae f.","fortūna fortūnae f."];
```

Please keep in mind that there is not always 4 `<li>` elements.

Is there any function that could do this?

Comment: An important clarification: do you have HTML as string, as collection of nodes you already picked, as contents of DOM...? Is it on serverside or clientside?

Comment: @Amadan All of this code is being done on clientside, the code is returned by a function. (Such as  `var bla = abc();` and the variable `blah` is the code above [In quotes])

Comment: What is the *original* source of the above HTML? If it is in the DOM (i.e., part of your page) then it would be easiest to get the data directly from there rather than having a function return the HTML as a string that then needs to be processed.

Comment: If this is a string, then so it as such in your question. As it is, the general assumption is that it is HTML which is in the DOM.

Comment: @nnnnnn I am using some functions to be run on another website, I just need the data to be scraped out of that code to be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are starting from a string, you need to first have the browser parse the string into a DOM. You can do that by creating a dummy HTML element, and putting your raw HTML inside it as `innerHTML` property. Then you will be able to search it using `querySelectorAll` (or `getElementsByClassName`, but QSA is more powerful, and doesn't make a live collection, so bonus). When you have a collection of nodes, you can use `map` function to extract the `textContent`. `NodeList` that QSA returns is compatible with `map`, but doesn't actually have it, so we have to "borrow" it from the array prototype.

Note that you should use `textContent` and not `innerHTML` to extract your strings, because if you have `"fort&#x016b;na"` instead of `"fortūna"` in your HTML (both of which have the same meaning in HTML, but the first one is encoding-agnostic), `innerHTML` will give you the former, and `textContent` will give you the latter.

```js
var rawHTML = '<li class="shiny-box choice clearfix" data-choice-id="0"> <span class="index">1.</span> <span class="val ">vīta vītae f.</span> <span class="marking-icon"></span> </li> <li class="shiny-box choice clearfix" data-choice-id="1"> <span class="index">2.</span> <span class="val ">patria patriae f.</span> <span class="marking-icon"></span> </li> <li class="shiny-box choice clearfix" data-choice-id="2"> <span class="index">3.</span> <span class="val ">poena poenae f.</span> <span class="marking-icon"></span> </li> <li class="shiny-box choice clearfix" data-choice-id="3"> <span class="index">4.</span> <span class="val ">fortūna fortūnae f.</span> <span class="marking-icon"></span> </li>';

var root = document.createElement('div');
root.innerHTML = rawHTML;
var valNodes = root.querySelectorAll('.val');
var texts = Array.prototype.map.call(valNodes, node => node.textContent);
console.log(texts);
```

Comment: Thanks for the second thought, I have a special function to convert the Latin in cryllic. Thank you sooooo much. I thought it could'nt be done.

Answer (score 2):

Using Regex:

```
var rawHTML = '<li class="shiny-box choice clearfix" data-choice-id="0"> <span class="index">1.</span> <span class="val ">vīta vītae f.</span> <span class="marking-icon"></span> </li> <li class="shiny-box choice clearfix" data-choice-id="1"> <span class="index">2.</span> <span class="val ">patria patriae f.</span> <span class="marking-icon"></span> </li> <li class="shiny-box choice clearfix" data-choice-id="2"> <span class="index">3.</span> <span class="val ">poena poenae f.</span> <span class="marking-icon"></span> </li> <li class="shiny-box choice clearfix" data-choice-id="3"> <span class="index">4.</span> <span class="val ">fortūna fortūnae f.</span> <span class="marking-icon"></span> </li>';

var myArray = [];
var myRegexp = /<span class="val ">(.*?)<\/span>/g;
match = myRegexp.exec(rawHTML);
while (match != null) {
  myArray.push(match[1]);
  match = myRegexp.exec(rawHTML);
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/jowgypmp/1/)

Comment: This does not work, given the clarification from the OP. He does not have `.val` in DOM.

Comment: @Amadan You are correct. I have modified my answer.